# Estoy realizando un sistema de punto de ventas para una farmacia pero tengo un problema. Espero me puedan ayudar!

Tags: java, mysql

Hasta ahora en mi programa hago el registro de productos en el que ya se encuentra el costo, el stock y todos esos datos.

Pero lo que no puedo hacer es que cada venta que se registre se almacene en la misma base de datos. Como puedo relacionar las tablas para que en la tabla de ventas se pueda ingresar el id del producto y así poder tomar el costo del producto y algunos datos mas. les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

El proyecto lo estoy desarrollando en Java con el `IDE Netbeans` y la base de datos es `MySQL` desde `WampServer`

Comment: Saludos, muestra el código que tienes hasta el momento, para que te puedan ayudar, además mira [ask] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Además deberías realizar el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.

Comment: te recomiendo aprender SQL

Comment: El signo de exclamación en el titulo que pusiste me hace pensar que nos estas gritando. A nadie le gusta que le griten!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para poder realizar lo que quieres, necesitaras crear dos tablas adicionales además de **productos**, un ejemplo sería. [image: Estructura sugerida]

Dónde la tabla de **venta** guardara todos los datos que necesites de la venta, ya sea hora, fecha, etc. Y la tabla **detalle_venta** servira para guardar todos los **productos** que necesites registrar para la **misma venta**. Al hacerlo de esta manera podras registrar todos los productos al mismo tiempo, en vez de tener que repetir el proceso por cada producto que necesites vender.